# SES : Unable to send email on dot net core docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, amazon-ses

So, I managed to create a console app that sends email via SES with reference to this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-net.html

I've developed it in a Windows environment and it's all working fine.

I then published it into a self-contained application and host it on docker (linux container) using the following command :

```
docker run -it --name testEmailService -v ${PWD}:/var/test -v <credentiallocation>:/.aws/credentials microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime
```

When I then run it inside docker, I keep on getting an error message that says **Connection Refused**.

Anyone has tried to do something similar before and got it to work successfully?

Comment: You're using the `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime` in your run command. 
Is that just for explanatory purposes? Shouldn't it be the name of your published image?

Comment: I'm using microsoft's image, loading my dotnet published files into the container with the first -v in and running dotnet <project>.dll

Comment: Is it since you're credentials are mounted into `/.aws/credentials` and not into `<docker container's user's home>/.aws/credentials`, eg `/root/.aws/credentials` if you're root, else `/home/foobar/.aws/credentials`

Comment: hey @byrnedo, i'm logged in as root and tried as you suggested /root/.aws/credentials (seems right from [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/create-shared-credentials-file.html) ) but still the exact same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure out. turns out it was two silly mistakes :

1) the first mistake was pointed out by byrnedo (thanks!) that I did not put the .aws folder into the root folder.

2) secondly, I accidentally put it into /root/.aws/credentials instead of /root/.aws which created an additional folder credentials

so this solved it :

```
docker run -it --name testEmailService -v ${PWD}:/var/test -v <credentiallocation>:/root/.aws microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime
```